# Consulta con Left Join en Django

Tags: sql, django

tengo una duda sobre si es posible con el ORM de Django, realizar el siguiente SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM `pot010` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `pot042` ON (`pot010`.`ninp10` = `pot042`.`ninp42`and COSE42 = 20202021)
```

Muchas gracias!
Saludos.

Comment: El ORM tiene como objetivo que no realices consultas SQL directamente. ¿Obedece esa consulta a una definición en el modelo de datos? ¿Se puede lograr mediante filtros en los modelos relacionados?
Tienes también la posibilidad de anular el ORM y utilizar SQL, pero no sé si es lo que te interesa.

Comment: @Sokkian, gracias por responder. Yo necesito lograr con el ORM una consulta equivalente al SQL que publiqué. Lo ves posible? Gracias.

Comment: No podría responderte sin ver los modelos, pero me sorprendería que no fuera posible